# Can I save the split character of a string in Perl

Tags: perl, split

I want to split a multi sentence paragraph into its constituent sentences whilst retaining the split characters ie the '**. ? !**'.  The code I'm using is:

```
my @Sentence = split(/[\.\?\!]/,$Paragraph);
```

Is there any way that I can save those sentence terminators?

Comment: You should add test cases, sample input and expected output.

Comment: `split /[.?!]\K/` would keep the terminator, and it would be attached to the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you add parentheses around the delimiter, they will be included in the result list.

```
my @Sentence = split /([\.\?\!])/, $Paragraph;
```

E.g. if you have the string `foo.bar.baz` before you would get `qw(foo bar baz)`, and with parentheses you would get `qw(foo . bar . baz)`.

In case you want to keep the delimiters attached to the sentence, you could use a lookbehind assertion

```
my @Sentence = split /(?<=[\.\?\!])/, $Paragraph;
# result qw(foo. bar. baz)
```

If you want to strip unnecessary spaces after the match, you could use `/(?<=[\.\?\!]) */`.